# GitLab - Docker - WindowsContainer - ASP.Net Core publish error when Release tag

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I run (inside Dockerfile) `RUN dotnet publish --output /app/` process/build is run successfully.
But when I run with `Release`: `RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ -c Release` I get error in GitLab console:

```
C:\source\Web.Core\Web.Core.csproj(34,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\source\Web.Core\\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Web.Core.dll" because it was not found.
  Web.Library.Tests -> C:\app\
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet publish --output /app/ -c Release' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Does anybody have any clue, why build process failed with `-c Release`? Same command `dotnet publish --output /app/ -c Release` run successfully from `Windows PowerShell`.

My GitLab runner and Docker are installed on my Windows 10 Pro.

What is strange is that it tries to copy from `bin\Debug`. I would expect from `bin\Release`. I understand file can't be found in `Debug`. But I can't figure it out, what I messed up in `Dockerfile`.

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /source

# caches restore result by copying csproj file separately
COPY Web.sln ./src/aspdocker/Web.sln

COPY Web.Library/Web.Library.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Library/
COPY Web.Core/Web.Core.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Core/
COPY Web.Hosting/Web.Hosting.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Hosting/
COPY Web.Library.Tests/Web.Library.Tests.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Library.Tests/
COPY Web.Core.Tests/Web.Core.Tests.csproj ./src/aspdocker/Web.Core.Tests/

# caches restore result by copying csproj file separately
RUN dotnet restore ./src/aspdocker/Web.sln

# copies the rest of your code
COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ -c Release
#RUN dotnet publish --output /app/

# Stage 2
#FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app .
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```